# Google Smart Home - Report State Real-Time Feed

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I have an application that receives and run correctly the SYNC, QUERY, EXECUTE sent by Google Actions.

I too configured  Report State in HomeGraph console. It works fine, but when I send a change report command to HomeGraph and it's accepted, nothing is updated in the Google home app, is this right? is the correct behavior?

I forget to do something else?

My sync response sends the device with willRportSate: true

tks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an HTTP 200 response from your report state command, you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented **HomeGraph** to my action. I found that if there is something wrong with the request google will return some error in the form of JSON with a different status code.

But as it is said above, if you got `200 OK`, then everything is OK from your side. For my requests, I get a response with the `uuid` that I give with a `200 OK` status code.